# Can I use gcloud firestore export command for incremental exports from firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

The gcloud firestore export command:

```
gcloud firestore export gs://bucket --collection-ids=''
```

takes a full export of my specified collections but I want to take incremental exports of only my new documents added on a daily basis. How do I achieve that? Can the gcloud firestore export command be modified in some way to just take exports of new documents being added to my collections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not currently a capability of Firestore or gcloud.

If you want to perform incremental exports, you will have to write some code or use another tool for that.  The tool will need a way to know how to query for data since some point in time, and you will need data in your documents to support that.  For example, you would need to have some sort of timestamp that indicates the last time the document was modified, so that it can be targeted in a query.